# How to use external PHP class file in Yii2 action

Tags: php, file, include, yii2

```
I want to implement twillio API in Yii2.
On submit form SMS should be sent.

I placed all twillio library code in advanced yii2 app in :

rr.lcl/library/twilli_lib/
```

rr.lcl is my root folder(advanced)

```
Here is my function:

public function actionSendtestsms($id) {
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/rr.lcl/library/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php')
        $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

}
```

How to include external php calss file in Yii2 controller function.

Answer (score 0):

Install Twillio PHP sdk via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)(in root of Yii2 run):

```
php /path/to/composer.phar require 'twilio/sdk:4.2.1'
```

It's added libarary to Yii2 autoloading and after that in your action simply do:

```
public function actionSendtestsms($id) {
      $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);
}
```

[See Twilio php sdk on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/twilio/sdk)

Comment: Thanks for replay but the issue has been resolved by Curl

Comment: Be sure to add a backslash or it'll look for a controller, e.g. $client = new \Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);